# Mapping Hibernate : <composite-id> 3

Tags: java, hibernate, composite-primary-key

I have a problem mapping to my webapp, I have a table (TacheTicket) contains two primary key and the mapping file I put the following code:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.model.TacheTicket" table="TACHETICKET">
        <composite-id>
         <key-property name="idTache" column ="idTache" type="com.model.Tache"/>
         <key-property name="idTicket" column="idTicket" type="com.model.Ticket"/>

       </composite-id> 
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

but when I execute the program this error appear :

```
 org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.model.Tache, at table: TACHETICKET, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(idTache)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildStandardProperty(PropertyFactory.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentMetamodel.<init>(ComponentMetamodel.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.buildType(Component.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getType(Component.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1108)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1293)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:855)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:774)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1460)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1398)
    ... 21 more
```

Table definition.

```
CREATE TABLE gestionticket.tacheticket (  
        idTachet INT NOT NULL,  idTicket INT NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (idTachet, idTicket), INDEX idTicket_idx (idTicket ASC), 
        CONSTRAINT idTache FOREIGN KEY (idTachet) REFERENCES gestionticket.tache (idTache) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION, 
        CONSTRAINT idTicket FOREIGN KEY (idTicket) REFERENCES gestionticket.ticket (idTicket) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Comment: can you provide table structure, ie field name and types

Comment: @AmitChotaliya the table Structure : CREATE TABLE `gestionticket`.`tacheticket` (
  `idTachet` INT NOT NULL,
  `idTicket` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idTachet`, `idTicket`),
  INDEX `idTicket_idx` (`idTicket` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `idTache`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idTachet`)
    REFERENCES `gestionticket`.`tache` (`idTache`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `idTicket`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idTicket`)
    REFERENCES `gestionticket`.`ticket` (`idTicket`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

Comment: In your question, formatted, not in a comment.

Comment: The hibernate code in your question does not define two primary keys, it defines one primary key with two columns.

Comment: Your SQL requires that IDTicket is a primary key of (or unique in) gestionticket. And your SQL requires that IDTache is a primary key of (or unique in) gestionticket. But are they? Or does gestionticket have a composite primary key (or unique column pair) (IDTicket,IDTache)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to create many to many relationship between `tache` and `ticket`.
You don't need configuration for the third table in hibernate.

You just have to configure the two tables with many-to-many tag.
Checkout [this](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example/) blog.

Answer (score 0):

You need `type="int"` to agree with the table definition.

Comment: but where I can set that IDTicket is a primary key of the table  ticket and even  thing IDTach...

Comment: That is a different question. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And write very clearly. Write like we don't know anything about what you have done or what you want to do. Because we don't.